# angular js - ajax call result needed in a service which is used by the controller

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I need a way to use a `json` retrieved data in a service which is used by a controller to populate it's template with the values returned from the service.

What I'm trying to do over all is to populate templates with content of a selected language that will change on user selection(I'm far from that right now but this it's a step )

**Controller**

```
(function(){
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('meniuController', ['$http', '$stateParams', '$scope', 'GetDataService', 'PageProperties', 
            function($http, $stateParams, $scope, GetDataService, PageProperties){      
    var page = "meniu";
    var path = '_global/views/services/json/' + $stateParams.lang + '_data.json';

    GetDataService.getData(path).then(function(result){         
        $scope.props = PageProperties.setProps(page, result.data);
    });
}])})();
```

**GetDataService**

```
(function(){
angular.module('myApp').factory('GetDataService',['$http','$q' , function($http, $q) {
   return {
        getData: function(path) {
             return $http.get(path)
                       .then(function(result) {
                            return $q.when(result.data);
                        },

                  function (httpError) {

                     throw httpError.status + " : " + 
                           httpError.data;
                  });
        }
   }
}]);})();
```

**PageProperties service**

```
(function(){
angular.module('NimbusApp').service('PageProperties',['$http','GetDataService', function($http, GetDataService) {

    this.setProps = function(page, data) {                      

        //here I want to access returned data from getdataService
        var properties = {
                isCenterActive : isActive_val,
                titleClass : page, 
                title : data.titles[page],
                leftLink : leftLink_val,
                leftFooterClass: leftLink_val,
                leftTitle: data.titles[leftLink_val],
                centerLink : centerLink_val,
                centerFooterClass: data.titles[centerLink_val],
                centerTitle : centerTitle_val,
                rightLink : rightLink_val,
                rightFooterClass: rightLink_val ,
                rightTitle : data.titles[rightLink_val],            
            }

        return properties;
    }
}]);})();
```

I get the following error

> angular-1.5.8.js:13920 SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 4
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at fromJson (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:1333:14)
>       at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:10635:16)
>       at http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:10726:12
>       at forEach (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:321:20)
>       at transformData (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:10725:3)
>       at transformResponse (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:11577:21)
>       at processQueue (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:16383:28)
>       at http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:16399:27
>       at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/_global/lib/js/angular-1.5.8.js:17682:28)(anonymous function) @ angular-1.5.8.js:13920(anonymous function) @ angular-1.5.8.js:10467processQueue @ angular-1.5.8.js:16391(anonymous function) @ angular-1.5.8.js:16399$eval @ angular-1.5.8.js:17682$digest @ angular-1.5.8.js:17495$apply @ angular-1.5.8.js:17790done @ angular-1.5.8.js:11831completeRequest @ angular-1.5.8.js:12033requestLoaded @ angular-1.5.8.js:11966

And the thrown exception

> angular-1.5.8.js:13920 undefined : undefined

Is this the correct way to do it? Because seems like the template is rendered with no values before the success result of getDataService

Comment: seems pretty obvious from error that the json is invalid..what's the question?

Comment: my json file is like this:
`{
 titles : {
    title1: "title 1 text",
    title2: "title 2 text", 
                                title3: "title 3 text", 
   },
 val1: "val1_text",
 val2: "val2 text",
}`

Comment: now I see that I don't have double quotes for tiles, val1, val2 ..

Comment: I've got 3 `ui-sref` links that gets pupulated before ajax succes -so I get errors there